# Type conversion needs unwrap?

Tags: swift, type-conversion, option-type

```
var a: String = "1"
var b: Int = Int(a)
```

The example above triggers an error saying that `Int` needs to be unwrapped.

```
var a: String = "1"
var b = Int(a)
```

However if we dismiss the type when declared b and do the same thing, it won't trigger any error.

What is the difference between the two approach? Why the first one needs to be unwrap even though it is not declared as optional?

Comment: "Why the first one needs to be unwrap even though it is declared as optional?" It's not declared optional.

Comment: sorry, it is just a typo

Comment: first one will return `Int?` which you cannot store in `Int` while the second is type inferred to be `Int`.

Comment: Your edit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/20776977) is pretty big. I don't have time now to check it out. Can you add a new answer instead?

Comment: sorry, but I think I'm too lazy to do that. I'll just leave it be. Plus it makes no sense to me with what the approver has said. if the content doesn't work anymore, it needs update. So I'll just leave it like that without any changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because in first example you are saying that `b` is of type `Int` and in second example since you did not make type explicit compiler sets it to `Int?`.

It is because `Int(string)` will only work if string can be interpreted as `Int`, so `Int("3")->3` but what should it do if you say `Int("text")->nil`, because it is not able to parse string into a an `Int`

You could provide a default value if you wanted in the first example and then it would be OK.

`var b: Int = Int(a) ?? 0`

Comment: So, that means if I don't declare type explicitly, it will unwrap automatically?

Comment: No, check type of b in second example it is `Int?` so if you want to use it you would have to unwrap it first

Comment: Remember if first example it is `Int` and in second `Int?` these are not same type...first one can never be nil, but second can be

Comment: Thanks a lot, got it now!

Comment: In second case compiler simply does type for you so it goes from `var b = Int(a)` to `var b:Int? = Int(a)`

Comment: Why conversion between different types needs it to be optional? Is it because it has the possibility to be nil like you said earlier?

Comment: Yes, what should Swift do if you say `Int("Slick")` should it be `0` should it be some random number?, no it will be `nil` since it cannot turn `Slick` into a `Int`

Comment: You can also accept the answer by tapping the green checkmark in my answer to mark it answered

Comment: yeah i want to do it but cannot need one more minute